# Excel price function what is meant by DSC,E,A?

Tags: excel, financial, trading

In excel PRICE function there are constants DSC,E,A what are these values? It is very confusing when there are more than one coupon period available for the bond.

[image: excel price function]

They have provided explanation for DSC,E,A  as follows.

DSC = number of days from settlement to next coupon date.

E = number of days in coupon period in which the settlement date falls.

A = number of days from beginning of coupon period to settlement date.

I am currently implementing a trading platform and i have given the following information.

- Dated Date - 1-Jan-10
- Coupon date before the settlement date - 1-Jul-12
- First Coupon Date after settlement date - 1-Jan-13
- Maturity Date - 1-Jan-17
- Yld - 7.5000%
- Frequency - 2
- rate - 12%
- redemption - 100
- Settlement Date - 15-Aug-12
- N - 9 coupon periods available

but i am struggling to find values for DSC,E and A.
Please be kind enough to help me put on this.

Answer (score 0):

According to my calculations:

```
DSC = 139 (Next coupon date - settlement date)
E = 184 (Next coupon date - current coupon date)
A = 45 (Settlement date - current coupon date)
```

Comment: Hi Robby, is DSC=139 and E=184 thorough out the summation? Because according to the definition i feel like it should change for each loop.